# Web table scraping: for loop stops after first iteration

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am doing a web table scraping task and the following is a part of my project. Why do I only get the printed result from the first loop - the loop stops after the first run?

```
 from lxml import html
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests  

 page = requests.get(link)
 tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
 web = page.text    
 soup = BeautifulSoup(web, 'lxml')

 table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "tc_table"})               

 for tr in table:
     tds = tr.find_all('td')
     name = tds[1].text
     description1 = tds[2].text
     description2 = tds[3].text
     print(name)
     print(description1)
     print(description2)
```

Comment: You loop iterates over the tables in the page not over the trs as the variable name suggests.

Comment: oh I see the problem. thanks!